# change text color of Bar Button Item from storyboard

Tags: ios, ios6

I have dragged and dropped Bar Button Item in Storyboard over navigation bar created by storyboard.
I would like to know how to change text color of Bar Button Item from storyboard ?
I have tried creating an outlet for bar button item then tried  :
`[myBackButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]];`

even tried barbuttonItem :

```
[myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but I am getting an error .   I tried changing tint the background color changes but the text color is still white How do I Change the text color to black?
 Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In your first code example, you have extra brackets surrounding it. Does that code work if you remove them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the text color using [Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-SW43).  For instance,

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor redcolor]};
[myButton setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Awesome Its working. Thanks Adam.Create outlet and add **[_item setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];** in ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```